# Integrating for Probability

Tags: probability, integration

[image]

I'm confused on what the area of integration would be for c) $P(X^2 > Y)$.

When I sketched it, I assumed that for $x$, the area of integration would be $0 < x < 1$ and for $y$,  $0 < y < x^2$, but I'm not sure if that is correct. Can someone verify?

Comment: You are just integrating over those points in $[0,1]\times [0,1]$ where we have that $x^2>y$. What you wrote seems fine for bounds of integration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*In principle*, we are integrating the joint density over the part of the plane which is below $y=x^2$. In practice, since the joint  density is $0$ outside the square $0\lt x\lt 1$, $0\lt y\lt 1$, we are integrating $x+y$ over the *part $P$ of the square* that is below the curve $y=x^2$. So the probability is
$$\iint_P (x+y)\,dx\,dy.$$

Draw a picture, noting that the parabola $y=x^2$ goes through the top right corner of the square. The required probability is given by the iterated integral
$$\int_{x=0}^1\left(\int_{y=0}^{x^2}(x+y)\,dy\right)\,dx.$$

Comment: Why wouldn't I be able to integrate dxdy in that order?

Comment: You certainly could. Then $x$ goes from $\sqrt{y}$ to $1$, and later $y$ goes from $0$ to $1$. To my mind that calculation is significantly messier, that's why I chose to integrate first with respect to $y$.